# Windows App Certification Kit - packagefullname bug W8 Store

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, wack

When I want to certify my application (Metro application) with the Windows App Certification Kit, I click on store and when the Windows App Certification Kit is launched it goes into preparing to validate app and then I get the error message:

> The Windows App Certification Kit experienced the following failure while validating your app.

The {0} cannot continue testing since the specified  Windows App store was was not found.  Please verify that the packagefullname is correct"

How can the packagefulname not be correct since I am not the one that typed it?  I use the GUI in VS 2012.

When launch the command `Get-AppxPackage > out.txt` in power shell I can see that my app has a package full name so even when I try to launch the command prompt

```
.\appcert.exe test -apptype metrostyle –packagefullname XXXXXXXXXX_neutral__823pgb98jhb94 -reportoutputpath c:\temp\MyWACKReport.xml
```

It says that the package full name must be specified with is the case so I really don't understand.  What can I do so that my application can pass Windows App Certification.

My machine: Windows 8 Pro x64 with VS 2012 ultimate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install the application prior to running the certification kit?

It is somewhat annoying that appcert.exe can't install a package itself. (Which is why we developed some tooling to do that for us, hopefully we'll open-source it soon...)

Comment: I am answering your question after a very long time sorry but, after installing the new version of the certification kit (2.2), this problem was resolved.